# Why Can't I Program my Atmega168 Pro Mini?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-pro-mini

I'm trying to program a Atmega168 Pro Mini 3.3V/8mhz I bought online. I followed a [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Program-Arduino-Pro-Mini-Using-Arduino-UNO/#discuss) that walks through the steps of how to program a Pro Mini with an Arduino Uno. However, in their example they are uploading code to a Atmega328 Pro Mini though I don't think it matters.

Anyway, I followed the same steps as they did (namely hooking up Uno's ground -> ground, 3v -> Vcc, Reset -> DTR, tx->tx, rx->rx). When I attempted to upload via Arduino IDE I got the message that the programmer was not responding. I also noticed that the transfer led on the Uno was not lighting up. Did I screw up something? Also, are my hookups correct? I would think tx pin should connect to rx pin, but I just followed the instructions. Would appreciate any thoughts

[image]

Comment: Did you remove the MCU from the Uno?

Comment: yup, I took off the 328 chip

Comment: Hookup is not correct, the RX, TX lines need to be crossed!

Comment: @UmarSear That's wrong. In this instance the Uno is only being used as a USB to UART adaptor, so TX->TX and RX->RX is correct. You would swap them only if you wanted the ATMega328P on the Uno to communicate with the ATMega168 on the Pro Mini.

Answer (score 1):

Your hookup seems to be correct. However check if there is a capacitor on the pro-mini board between DTR and reset pin, some arduino clones don't come with one.
If there isn't any you can simply connect a capacitor like this:
Reset pin (Arduino Uno) -> Capacitor (0.01uF for example) -> DTR (pro mini). The reason for this hookup is exmplined well [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=26877.0)

Comment: They're also interfacing the 5V UNO to the 3.3V Pro Mini with no consideration for the logic level difference.  Sometimes you get away with that.  Anyway, rather the start another answer, I figured I'd just tack this onto yours, for integration into it or not.